# Assembly Binding redirect changed upon compile

Tags: nuget, azure-service-fabric, assembly-binding-redirect, assemblybinding

I have a service that references few other libraries in the same solution and some libraries via NuGet packages.

I have a library `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender` and another one `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabricNative` which seem to disagree on the version of `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`.

So in my app.config I have the following:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.15.0.44797" newVersion="2.15.0.44797" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

But when I go and see what the service.exe.config file contains after I compile I found:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.12.0.21496" newVersion="2.12.0.21496" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

which is strange as no other library in the solution has a reference to that version.

And this causes an issue where an exception is thrown and it says that cannot load version 2.12.0.21496 of such library.

What am I missing? Whey the arbitrary numbers despite all my attempts?

Note: these are services referencing other libraries in a service fabric solution

Comment: A reproducible example would be immensely helpful in determining the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just tried creating a console app, adding `PackageReference`s to the two packages (you have a typo in one of the package names, by the way), and when I build, the generated .config file has a binding redirect to version 2.15.0.44797.  I can't reproduce your problem.